# How do you solve this kind of 'glitching' when deforming/ rigging the mesh?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting

How do you solve this kind of 'glitching' when deforming/ rigging the mesh?

Video reference: https://cloudmails-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/tp053611_mail_apu_edu_my/EROWNm5PQbxDnr57ciz6Hs4B9H4sEDhU9E-5C-Kv0Brwqg?nav=eyJyZWZlcnJhbEluZm8iOnsicmVmZXJyYWxBcHAiOiJPbmVEcml2ZUZvckJ1c2luZXNzIiwicmVmZXJyYWxBcHBQbGF0Zm9ybSI6IldlYiIsInJlZmVycmFsTW9kZSI6InZpZXciLCJyZWZlcnJhbFZpZXciOiJNeUZpbGVzTGlua0NvcHkifX0&e=m8DJE9

[image]

Comment: Hello, have you merged the vertices? Maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: You can [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/310114/edit) the question to make it better.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: @moonboots I managed to solve the cracks by merging the vertices, thanks for the advice/ guidance~

Answer (score 0):

Your vertices are not merged, select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*